# Which gnu attributes have c++11 syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

The documentation for [C++11 attribute specifier sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) includes examples of GNU namespace attributes, e.g.

```
[[gnu::always_inline]] [[gnu::hot]] [[gnu::const]] [[nodiscard]]
inline int f(); // declare f with four attributes
```

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) for attributes prior to C++11 uses different syntax

```
__attribute__(( ... ))
```

I can't find documentation for which of the GNU attributes use the new `[[gnu:foo]]` syntax, or what the differences are.

Where is the definitive documentation for this?

Comment: How about the source code? :-P https://code.woboq.org/gcc/gcc/attribs.c.html#_Z15init_attributesv registers all the GCC specific attributes in the "gnu" namespace. (The tables are set up in a complicated way.)

Comment: @peppe The link is broken, this is a new one: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/attribs.cc

Comment: Right. Look for the `init_attributes` function, and specifically for `register_scoped_attributes (attribute_tables[i], "gnu");`

Answer (score 1):

This is a hole in the GCC documentation, and maintainers are aware of it. See [GCC Bug 102397 - Documentation of attribute syntax does not discuss C++11 / C23 attribute syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102397).

Presently, it looks like *all* GNU attributes are registered in the `gnu::` namespace:

```cpp
/* Put all the GNU attributes into the "gnu" namespace.  */
register_scoped_attributes (attribute_tables[i], "gnu");
```

[gcc-mirror, `attribs.cc`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/e7b585a468aa4980955ae25fa9f4b41a3dc2995e/gcc/attribs.cc#L350-L351C10)

Comment: UPDATE: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax now discusses the C++11/C23 syntax: "The standard ‘[[]]’ attribute syntax is recognized by GCC’s default language dialect for both C and C++." ... "When using GNU-specific attributes in the standard syntax, you must prefix their names with ‘gnu::’, such as gnu::section.".